# Allow users to delete or answer Facebook comments on my website or from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-comments

I am creating a website, something like business directory. I want to allow my users to have Facebook comments on their pages. As i read, i should connect comments with their Facebook ID so they can be allowed to delete them. I wanted to know, can my users answer or delete those comments directly from Facebook, or must they be only on my website to answer? I haven't reached yet to this part in developing but i want to know is this possible so i know in which direction i should go, or maybe find different solution...I know this is not strict programing question but i am asking if this can be programed? I am using zend2 framework, php.

EDIT:

On Facebook developers, section for comments, it states:
With the Comments Box, Facebook users on your site can comment on your content, post those comments to their profiles, and share them with their friends on Facebook. The Comments Box allows non-Facebook users to make comments on your site as well. And via our APIs, you can access related comments made on Facebook as well to bring the conversation together.

Does the last sentence confirms what i'm asking, can not quite understand it well...?

Answer (score 1):

Implement Facebook comments on your site as instructed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

You'll need a different Facebook App ID for each page in the directory--which is against Facebook guidelines but will allow each of your users to independently moderate the comments on their pages. If you use a single Facebook App ID everyone will see all comments on all pages on your site on the Facebook moderation page.

You and your users can't "delete" comments. You can only choose to show or hide them. (And that's if the commentator has set their comments to public.)

Your users will be able to moderate directly on their pages on your site or from the Facebook moderation page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

You can automate the setup part of this process when you create a user for your site.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I might not explained the problem well. I want from a user to connect his personal facebook account with my website, maybe just type his facebook ID so i can include him as a moderator, so that he can moderate comments on his pages on my website, or on his personal facebook profile. Is this possible? Thanks